# Print indices of the selected vertices

Tags: python, vertices, selection-tools

I'm trying to select some vertices in UV Editor and print them out using Python in blender. But when I use code like this:

```
import bpy
import bmesh

obj = bpy.context.object
print('Start')
if obj.mode == 'EDIT':
    bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(obj.data)
    bm.faces.active = None
    selected = [i.index for i in obj.data.vertices if i.select]
    print('Selected:', len(selected))
else:
    print("Object is not in edit mode.")
```

It always shows me that I selected all the vertices (no matter what I do in either UV editor or default 3D viewer).

Any ideas why? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Was accessing wrong object (facepalm)

```
import bpy
import bmesh

obj = bpy.context.active_object
print('Start')
if obj.mode == 'EDIT':
    bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(obj.data)    
    selected = [i.index for i in bm.verts if i.select == True]
    print('Selected:', len(selected))
else:
    print("Object is not in edit mode.")
```

But still, it works only in 3D view/edit mode, not from UV editor. Can anyone help, please?